# ajaxSubmit / function(data) call happening twice

Tags: ajax, ajaxsubmit

I am trying to upload a large file and having issues of submit happening twice. 
But not for small file sizes.
The $("#fileform").ajaxSubmit({ call seems to be happening twice or multiple times instead of once. Or the submit 'success : function(data) {' .
Not sure. I am able to see the details in 'commands_cvs_grpupload.jsp' twice.

HTML:

```
<form id="fileform" method="post" align="left">
    <input id="importFile" name="importFile" type="file" onkeydown="return   false"
           onpaste="return   false" ondragenter="return   false"/>
    <input id= "errorRecords" name = "errorRecords" type="hidden"/>
    <input id= "type" name = "type" value="BULK_UPLOAD" type="hidden"/>
    <input name="import" type="button" onClick="importCSV();" value="Import CSV"/>
```

Script for importCSV():

```
function importCSV(){
    if(checkFileIsNull()){
        $("#requiredFile").css("color","#000000");
        $("#requiredFileType").css("color","#000000");
        $("#gridWrapper").hide("slow");     
        configDisplayMessage("displayMessage","White");
        $("#displayMessage").html("");  
        $("#ui-progressbar-value").html("");
        $("#statusmessage").html("");
        $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
            value: 0
        });
        $("#processDiv").show();
        $("#progressbar").show();
        $("#statusmessage").show(); 
        $("#ui-progressbar-value").show();  
        $("#progressbar").html("Waiting...");
        // submit file to SBS; command is callaSBSImport
        submitFileToSBS();  
        // get status for SBS ; command is callSBSStatus 
        getStatusFromSBS();     
        startProcess = setInterval("getStatusFromSBS()",3000);      

    }else{
        $("#gridWrapper").hide("slow"); 
        $("processDiv").hide();
        $("#progressbar").hide();
        $("#statusmessage").hide();
        $("#ui-progressbar-value").hide();      
    }
}
```

Script for submitFileToSBS()

```
function submitFileToSBS(){         
    $("#fileform").ajaxSubmit({
        type : "post",
        url : "framework/commands_cvs_grpupload.jsp", 
        dataType:"json",
        data : "Command=callSBSGroup&Service=ComplianceValidation&Method=uploadGroupings",
        success : function(data) {              
            setProcessBar(100,"Process is done.");
            clearInterval(startProcess);
            errorRecords =  Array();
            var list = "";
            var stringBuilder = "";             
            /*MY CODE*/
        },
        error : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            /*MY CODE*/
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: how many requests to a server you see in browser's dev tool?

Comment: It's a single file upload.

Comment: Having this issues if the file has around 10,000 records. Don't find this issue if file has around 1000 records to be processed.

Comment: Code formatted @IuriiDrozdov

Comment: where is html code ?

Comment: There is another request to get the status of file upload, but the call is to a different function.

Comment: Included the HTML @shareef

Comment: could you please provide a code of importCSV()?

Comment: importCSV is just calling the function submitFileToSBS() @IuriiDrozdov. Please find the same added.

Comment: it would be really great if you prepare jsfidle for this

Comment: @shareef, thank u. Sry that does not help in this situation.

Comment: The issue is the $.ajax({ is submitting twice

Comment: or the function(data) is being sent twice